# Remove text within parentheses in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm looking for a way to remove text within parentheses ()

for example

My name is (was) John -> my name is John.

Thanks!

Comment: See also https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm and https://intelligentediting.com/blog/using-word-wildcards-in-the-real-world/.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

- Start the Find and Replace dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Go to the Replace tab
- Click More
- Click Use wildcards
- Set "Find what" to `[(]*[)]`
- Click Replace All.

This might leave you with too many blanks around "(John)",
and in that case either add the blank to the Find string,
or replace later two blanks by one.

Comment: Great, somehow it worked! Thank you!